# Magento 2 show custom table data on the admin order detail tab

Tags: admin, sales-order, magento2.3.3

I am building a custom module to store multiple rows of custom data while user placing the order. Following fields are in my custom table, `“entity_id”, “order_id”, “sku”, “some_customvalue”, “create_at”, “updated_at”.` Once user place the order, values are adding to the table without any issue, but I need to show this value in the admin order details page in a tab and customer account order details page in a tab.

I created the tab in the admin order details page but I don’t know how to show the data from the custom table belongs to each order.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks.